# a problem in elementary number theory :$n=a+b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how to prove if $n\in \Bbb N $and $n\gt 6$ then there exists $a,b \in \Bbb N $ such that $ a,b\ge 2$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1 $ and $n=a+b$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the $a,b$ for $n=6$? Maybe is $n>6$...

Comment: I think you mean for $n > 6$. Try out for a few numbers and see if you can find some pattern. Start with odd $n$. Can you extend the idea there to even $n$? If not, break even into more cases...

Comment: You've already deleted at least one question you posted in the last few minutes.  Are you sure you want answers?

Comment: @polkjh,that's right.tnx

Comment: @hardmath the previous question exists prior in the post of maisam

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that.  Thanks!

Comment: For n=6, the possibilities are (2,4) and (3,3) which don't meet the condition for why n has to be bigger than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\rm\:n = a\!+\!b\:$ then $\rm\: 1=(a,b)=(a,n\!-\!a) = (a,n).\,$ Note $\rm\,a,b\ge 2$ $\iff$ $\rm a\ne 1,\ a\ne n\!-\!1.\,$ Thus we need to prove that there is some $\rm\ a\in[2,\,n\!-\!2]\ $ such that $\rm\ a\ $ is coprime to $\rm\,n,\ $ i.e. $ $  that $\rm\,phi(n) > 2.\ $ If you know Euler's phi formula then this is simple.
Otherwise, if $\rm\,n>3\,$ is odd, choose $\rm\,a=2;\,$ else $\rm\,n\,$ is even, so $\rm\,n = 2^k m,\,$ for odd $\rm\,m.\:$ Show that $\rm\ a = 2\!+\!m\ $ works for $\rm\,n>6.$

**Remark** $\ $ Above we constructed a smaller natural $\rm\,2\!+\!m\,$ coprime to $\rm\:2^k m\:$ by splitting it into coprime factors, then adding them (or their radicals). This is the same construction used in variant of Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes. This uses $\rm\:(n,m)=1\:\Rightarrow\:(nm,\,n\!+\!m) = 1\:$. Thus any factorization $\rm\:k = nm\:$ into coprime factors yields a number $\rm\,n\!+\!m\,$ coprime to $\rm\,k,\,$ and which, generally, is smaller than $\rm\,k\,$ (as we need above). Being coprime to $\rm\,k\,$ and $> 1$ it has a prime factor not in $\rm\,k,\,$ hence it yields a "new" prime.

Ribenboim attributes this form of Euclid's proof to Stieltjes (1890) (but I would not be surprised if it is much older). Note that Euclid's proof is a special case, using a trivial factorization, i.e. $\rm\,m = 1.$

A proof that $\rm\,(n,m)=1\,\Rightarrow\,(nm,n\!+\!m)=1\,$ is easy. First $\rm\,1 = (n,m) = (n,n\!+\!m).\, $  Similarly $\rm\,(m,n\!+\!m)=1,\:$ thus $\rm\,(nm,n+m)=1\:$ follows by a form of Euclid's Lemma: if both $\rm\,n,m\,$ are coprime to an integer, then so too is their product. This coprimality often proves handy.

Comment: that's right.$(2+m,n-2+m)=d$then $d|n=2^km$ since d is odd or even so $(d,m)=1$ or $(d,2)=1$ .if $d|m$ then $d|2$ that is not true.if $d|2$ then $d|m$ is not true.now why $n-(2+m) \neq 1$?

Comment: $n-(2+m)\neq1$ because $2^km-m-2=2^k(m-1)-2=2^{k+1}l-2\neq 1$ .since $m$ is odd so $m-1$ is even,also $n$ is even so k\ge 1 also $n\neq 2$ so $m\neq 1$ so $l\neq 0$.then 2^{k+1}l-2 \ge 2.proof is compelete . tnx

Comment: @agustin Simpler, since $\rm\,2\!+\!m\:$ is odd, $\rm\:(2\!+\!m,2^km) = (2\!+\!m,m) = (2,m)= 1,\:$ by $\rm\,m\,$ odd. Note that I added a remark about this sort of coprime construction.

Comment: why $a\le n-2$ ?

Comment: that's right.we can show this with induction.$3+\frac{2l}{2^k} \lt 2l-1$,,$3+\frac{2l+2}{2^k} \lt 2l+\frac{2}{2^k} \lt 2l+2 $

Comment: @agustin $ \,a\le n-2\,$ since if $\,a = n-1\,$ then $\,b=1\,$ contra $\,b\ge 2\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

Take one of $a,\ b$ to be the smallest prime $p$ with $p\nmid n$ (then why $a,b\neq1?$).

Comment: I don't realize .then if one number is $p,$prime other number is ?

Comment: If $a=p$ we want $p+b=n$ so $b=?$ To show that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ consider all possibilities of $\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: ok.if nearestest prime $p$ with $p|n$ problem is solved because $gcd(p,n-p)=1$ or$p$.because if$=d$ then $d|p$ so $d=p$ or $1$ if $d=p$: $p|p,p|n-p,p|n$so $p|0$ therefore $d=1$

Comment: that's must be $p|n$ not $p\nmid n$

Comment: @agustin: Right! If $\gcd(p,n-p)=d=p$ then ... $p\mid n$ ↯. Therefore $d=1$. Now why $n-p\neq 1$?